# Open word using vba Mac - OS X

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I am trying to open automatically an excel document on a Mac OS X, but it doesn't work. My code is:

```
Sub Button81_Click()
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("/Users/ricardo/Miniman/miniman_uti.docx")
    objWord.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Will the path be wrong? For this path "/Users/ricardo/Miniman/miniman_uti.docx" it opens excel files. Why not word files?

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
sub Test()

dim objdoc as object

with CreateObject("word.application")
set objdoc = .documents.open("path")
end with

end sub
```

Comment: Yes, it is a docx file. Thank you for the code. However it only works if the microsoft word is not opened (for example with another document). That is, if we want to work with several word files it works only at the first time you want to open a word file.

Comment: Not completely understanding you at this moment. Do you have a certain variable in your path that is used to open more then one word doc?

Comment: No. If I have any other word file already opened before run this code, it doesn`t work, that is, it doesn`t open the file I want. If I don`t have word application opened before running this code it works.

Comment: I would like a code to open at any time regardless of whether or not I have one or more word files already opened before running this code. Did I explain better now? Thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

Code to safely open a word doc from a file.
Handles the case where you already have word open.

```
Dim w As Object
' If word is already open get ahold of the running instance
' Otherwise create a new instance
On Error Resume Next
Set w = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If w Is Nothing Then Set w = CreateObject("Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
' Close all open files and shutdown Word
' Loop through any open documents and close them
Do Until w.Documents.Count = 0
    w.Documents(1).Close
Loop
w.Quit False
Set w = Nothing

' Now that all instances of word are closed, open the template
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
wdApp.Visible = True
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="MYPATH")
```